# CSV import, only one column (Matlab/Octave)

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, octave, measurement

I have since several days problems with reading my measurement csv files and make some simple calculations. I hope someone can help me.

**My Aim**
Read CSV data file, as followed:

**Open with Excel:**

```
date: 20140202  time: 083736    Cycles total: 74127 T_zer: 56   T_op1: 90.000       
 Actu state: stoppes !  T1: -23 T2: -12 T3: -32 T4: -65     
*-*                     
324203  0   34724   0   0   0   2
431040  0   0   0   0   0   1
230706  0   0   0   0   0   1
340810  0   0   0   0   0   1
..............
....
.
```

-->Here 1st question: If I open with editor, I can only see one delimiter, its ";". But there must be two? One for row , one for columns? How can Excel separate it  correctly into row and col, if there is only ";" ?

However... now I tried to csvread this file with octave. There I get it into octave, but everything only in one column:/. For me it would be very comfortable Octave could read it into a 7x X Matrix. In this case I can handle the data easy.

Here my Code:

```
clc
clear all
[fname,pname] =uigetfile();

fname;
extra="/";
pname;

b=strcat(pname,extra,fname);

m = csvread(b);
```

**Result:**
m as double with 4003x1. 4003 is corretct, but everything in one colum:/

```
m =

       0
       0
       0
   454203
   561040
   340706
```

I tried now to handle this problem up to several days, but no result.

Comment: did you try xlsread? If excel is installed on the PC, xlsread uses excel to load the files, thus it reads everything excel reads. Otherwise: How does your file (plain text) look like? Excel removes the delimiters so the view in excel does not help.

Comment: thanks for fast answering.
Yes i also tryed xlsread to open csv file, than i get this message:

    Detected XLS interfaces: warning: xlsread: some elements in list of return values are undefined
    >>

He makes the m matrix double, but 0x0 :/

Generrly its possible to open csv file with xlsread?

How can i get the removed delimiters? In Editor view i also only see one delimiter ; ...mhhh...

What you mean with plain text? if i open my file with Editor?

Comment: Can you upload the file (or a shortened example) somewhere, there seems something wrong with the file. Normally the column separator is `;` and the row separator is `\n` (=new line). Probably textscan is required to parse the file manually.

Comment: What do the contents of the csv file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not a Octave expert, but looks like you can use the [dlmread](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFdlmread) function to read a CSV files, it has many parameters which can help you read the file correctly.

- start reading the data from row X (and not from the start)
- only have Y columns
- defined the separator between fields